# Do I have to manually fix an interrupted dist-upgrade?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, 17.10

During a run of `apt-get dist-upgrade`, I accidentally canceled it via Ctrl + C when it was setting up packages.

These packages were about to be updated:

```
aptdaemon aptdaemon-data google-chrome-unstable libsmbclient libwbclient0 python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets samba-libs
```

This is the run output until the cancelation:

```
Preparing to unpack .../0-google-chrome-unstable_66.0.3359.26-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-chrome-unstable (66.0.3359.26-1) over (66.0.3359.22-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../1-libsmbclient_2%3a4.6.7+dfsg-1ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsmbclient:amd64 (2:4.6.7+dfsg-1ubuntu3.2) over (2:4.6.7+dfsg-1ubuntu3.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../2-samba-libs_2%3a4.6.7+dfsg-1ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking samba-libs:amd64 (2:4.6.7+dfsg-1ubuntu3.2) over (2:4.6.7+dfsg-1ubuntu3.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../3-libwbclient0_2%3a4.6.7+dfsg-1ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libwbclient0:amd64 (2:4.6.7+dfsg-1ubuntu3.2) over (2:4.6.7+dfsg-1ubuntu3.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../4-aptdaemon-data_1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu17.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking aptdaemon-data (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu17.1) over (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu17) ...
Preparing to unpack .../5-python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets_1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu17.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu17.1) over (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu17) ...
Preparing to unpack .../6-aptdaemon_1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu17.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking aptdaemon (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu17.1) over (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu17) ...
Preparing to unpack .../7-python3-aptdaemon_1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu17.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-aptdaemon (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu17.1) over (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu17) ...
Setting up aptdaemon-data (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu17.1) ...
Setting up libwbclient0:amd64 (2:4.6.7+dfsg-1ubuntu3.2) ...
Setting up samba-libs:amd64 (2:4.6.7+dfsg-1ubuntu3.2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libsmbclient:amd64 (2:4.6.7+dfsg-1ubuntu3.2) ...
Setting up google-chrome-unstable (66.0.3359.26-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.26-0ubuntu2.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-1) ...
Setting up aptdaemon (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu17.1) ...
Setting up python3-aptdaemon (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu17.1) ...
Setting up python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu17.1) ...
W: Operation was interrupted before it could finish
```

I now wonder if there is anything in a broken state on my system. I tried running:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Yet nothing is reported.

If I run:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

noting changes. I wonder: Is there anything broken on my system? How can I know? And if something was broken, how would I fix it?

Comment: What about using forced reinstall `sudo apt install --reinstall aptdaemon aptdaemon-data google-chrome-unstable libsmbclient libwbclient0 python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets samba-libs` ?

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz At least that let all the scripts run again.  My system didn't seem unstable, yet I feel better about it now ;) Feel free to provide it as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can force reinstalling of packages (downloading and reinstalling again) by issuing this command:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall aptdaemon aptdaemon-data google-chrome-unstable libsmbclient libwbclient0 python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets samba-libs
```

Please note the additional `--reinstall` parameter next to standard `apt install` command.

This additional parameter is not documented in `man apt`, but it is on `man apt-get` :

```
--reinstall
Re-install packages that are already installed and at the newest version.
```

Comment: You could add where you can find the names updated on your last try, if you not have it one screen anymore, by default Ubuntu saves that info in `/var/log/apt/history.log` in append mode, so last entry is last performed action. Never the less +1 from me.